# need to deploy web app on server

Tags: java

I need to write a web app from scratch with a date picker that allows user to select date and then queries the database according to thee input provided by the user and displays results. This will be deployed on the companies web servers(they have various apps on a server). However, i have no idea where to start as i have never written a web app before. Also i will need a local test and prod environment set up. Where should i start, what all needs to be included in my classpath. How do i install build tools and configure them?Eventually more people will work on enhancing the app but i first need to get it set up and deployed on prod. This will be written in java.

Comment: Questions like this aren't really a good fit for Stack Overflow, you'd be better off hitting up Google for tutorials.

Comment: These are the kinds of questions you should ask someone at your company.  Unless yours is the first web application ever to be written at your company, they will already have web servers and a web application methodology.

Comment: First you have to list your requierments , then benchmark on the technologies that best fit your needs,and if you have problem, then post them here and we try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Cant comment due to low reputation, so i have to post my suggestion as an answer.

As JonK posted, this site is about specific code problems, but i'd suggest you looking into a few things, that might help you with your task.

Choosing from a various possibilities, is a tricky thing, and if i ware you, i would ask at your work with is more common there, so help with problems in development would be near ;)

**Spring framework** is quite popular and you will find plenty tutorials for it

**JSF** is a interesting one, and if you will choose this one, at SO, you can look into answers provided by user BalusC. As some one said to me, if Balus has written about something, then it is as he said ;)

**Struts** is not something that I've tied yet, but it is a choice.

And plenty more, most of them has been mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java)

But as i said, ask at your work place, what they are using.